# Cat7 cable not working

Tags: home-networking, cat7

I’m running cat7 cable and crimped both ends but at one end when testing light 4 doesn’t come on but at the other end they all come on but 4 and 5 come on at the same time. Any suggestions what the issue might be?

Comment: Suggestions..  DIY crimps are quite a dark art. Chop up some short lengths, waste some crimps & practise your technique.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin.  I done a test on a shorter length and that worked ok. I know it’s hard to tell but is the test result likely to be an issue with the crimps or could it be cable damage? The cable is in the walls so difficult to inspect for any damage when it was routed through

Comment: It sounds like a bad crimp - cut off the problem end and re-crimp. It could be cable damage, but it's more likely it's a bad crimp _(if two more crimps don't resolve, it's probably a bad cable)_

Comment: Given that lights 4 and 5 come on at the same time means that both wires touch the same pin. So its a bad crimp.

Comment: I think it must be my crimps, I now have lights in sequence 1-8 in one room but the sequence in the other end is  8,7,6,3,4,5,2,1. That would probably rule out a cable issue.It’s definitely a dark art

Comment: I managed to get this working after practicing my crimps, wasted a few but got there in the end. A bit over kill for home network but I have cat7 installed, thanks for everyone that responded